# Search redirect to default search url

Tags: wordpress

I have a home page. I have integrated search functionality on home. its works fine. when i have searched, url displayed http://localhost/site-name/?s=searchTerm. But when i have accessing inner page of website and i have search, url displaying is http://localhost/site-name/pageName/?s=searchTerm. How should i redirect to http://localhost/site-name/?s=searchTerm

Answer (score 1):

Set the search form like below. add the action equal to WordPress  home page URL `esc_url( home_url( '/' ) );`

```
<form method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" class="" id="">
```

Comment: not working. also in url, < is displaying after searching. and page is not redirecting to default search.

Comment: <form role="search" method="get" class="search-form form-inline pull-right" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
 <div class="form-group search-block">
  <label>
   <input type="search" class="search-field form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" value="" name="s">
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </label>
 </div>
</form> This code i have put in localhost/site-name/pageName.

Answer (score 0):

You are may be using the current page URL under your search form's action. Simply, you just have to change the action and point it to your home page URL.

```
action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"
```

This function will replace the action URL with your site's home directory.

Comment: `<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form form-inline pull-right" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
 <div class="form-group search-block">
  <label>
   <input type="search" class="search-field form-control search-input" placeholder="Search" value="" name="s">
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  </label>
 </div>
</form>`This code i have put in localhost/site-name/pageName.

Comment: This URL can help you a lot https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/ they have explained very nicely

Comment: I have used in action="/site-name". It redirected to search default page.